# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I trying to plot a bar chart using D3 and render it through React's render method.
My index.js is as follows,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Styles/index.css';
import BarChart from './Components/BarChart'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h3> SmaRT - A Dash Board</h3>
            <BarChart data={[1,3,5,7,11]} size={[500,500]}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Essetially, I passing data and size to the BarChart function. My BarChart.js is as follows,

```
import React from 'react';
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';
import { max } from 'd3-array';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import '../Styles/index.css';

class BarChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.createBarChart();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.createBarChart();
    }

    createBarChart() {
        const node = this.node;
        const dataMax = max(this.props.data);
        const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([0,dataMax]).range([0, this.props.size[1]]);

        select(node).select('div').data(this.props.data).enter().append('div')

        select(node).select('div').data(this.props.data).exit().remove()

        select(node).select('div').data(this.props.data).style('fill', '#FE9922').attr('x', (d,i) => i * 25).attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] - yScale(d))
        .attr('height', d => yScale(d)).attr('width', 25)
    }

    render(){
        return <svg ref={node => this.node = node} width={500} height={500}></svg>
    }
}

export default BarChart;
```

Inspecting the page elements reveals that the svg element is being rendered for the dimensions prescribed in BarChart.js but the function is not taking up the "size" parameter passed.

In addition, react developer tools through a error as follows,

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
>     at new EnterNode (enter.js?19a3:9)
>     at    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
>     at new EnterNode (enter.js?19a3:9)
>     at bindIndex (data.js?1427:21)
>     at Selection.__webpack_exports__.a [as data] (data.js?1427:100)
>     at BarChart.createBarChart (BarChart.js?1e85:26)
>     at BarChart.componentDidMount (BarChart.js?1e85:14)
>     at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:264)
>     at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:75)
>     at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:263)
>     at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js?7abf:76)
>     at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js?2d36:80)
>     EnterNode @ enter.js?19a3:9
>     bindIndex @ data.js?1427:21
>     __webpack_exports__.a @ data.js?1427:100
>     createBarChart @ BarChart.js?1e85:26
>     componentDidMount @ BarChart.js?1e85:14
>     (anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:264
>     measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:75
>     (anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:263
>     notifyAll @ CallbackQueue.js?7abf:76
>     close @ ReactReconcileTransaction.js?2d36:80
>     closeAll @ Transaction.js?91bc:209
>     perform @ Transaction.js?91bc:156
>     batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:126
>     perform @ Transaction.js?91bc:143
>     batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js?bdd7:62
>     batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?be0d:97
>     _renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:319
>     _renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:401
>     render @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:422
>     (anonymous) @ index.jsx?cca3:17
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:1047
>     __webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:63
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:66
>     bindIndex (data.js?1427:21)
>     at Selection.__webpack_exports__.a [as data] (data.js?1427:100)
>     at BarChart.createBarChart (BarChart.js?1e85:26)
>     at BarChart.componentDidMount (BarChart.js?1e85:14)
>     at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:264)
>     at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:75)
>     at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:263)
>     at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js?7abf:76)
>     at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js?2d36:80)
>     EnterNode @ enter.js?19a3:9
>     bindIndex @ data.js?1427:21
>     __webpack_exports__.a @ data.js?1427:100
>     createBarChart @ BarChart.js?1e85:26
>     componentDidMount @ BarChart.js?1e85:14
>     (anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:264
>     measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:75
>     (anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:263
>     notifyAll @ CallbackQueue.js?7abf:76
>     close @ ReactReconcileTransaction.js?2d36:80
>     closeAll @ Transaction.js?91bc:209
>     perform @ Transaction.js?91bc:156
>     batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:126
>     perform @ Transaction.js?91bc:143
>     batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js?bdd7:62
>     batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?be0d:97
>     _renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:319
>     _renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:401
>     render @ ReactMount.js?0cc2:422
>     (anonymous) @ index.jsx?cca3:17
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:1047
>     __webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:63
>     (anonymous) @ bundle.js:66
> ```

Could anyone shed some light on what is that I am doing wrong and how about figure that out?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the mistake, It was due to the select statement in the createBarChart function BarChart.js

```
select(node).selectAll('rect')
```

and not

```
select(node).select('div')
```

Somehow, the code was misplaced. *selectAll* in D3 selects all the matching keywords supplied to it as argument, in this case 'rect'. SVG should draw rectangles with the supplied. And exactly this has to be rendered.

Thank you all for those who attempted to comprehend and solve/debug this issue in their heads.